# Laravel 4 : Detect and update intended url

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4

How do I detect the intended URL and edit it, if the intended URL has a specific value like:

```
if($intended_url == 'http://.../logout')
{
    //forget or update it
    $intended_url = '/home';
}
```

Comment: Do you mean for a specific url - or for any url that contains "logout"?

Answer (score 3):

Laravel sets a `url.intended` session variable for intended URLs.

You could do this:

```
Route::get('/logout', function (){

      if (Session::get('url.intended')) == 'http://example.com/logout')
      {
           Session::put('url.intended', 'http://example.com/home');
      }
});
```

Comment: this will not help, when my user logout I redirect him to login page with message, then if he tried to login again with different username or same username, he return back to logout page

Comment: Sorry - I misunderstood your question. I've updated my answer.

Comment: can't return intended URL using: echo Session::get('url.intended');

Answer (score -2):

Use...

```
if (location.href =="http://google.com"){
alert('its google');
} else{
alert('location is ' + location.href);
};
```

window.location is the object to get this value.

You can assign by using

```
location.href = "http://hotmail.com";
```

Comment: -1, wrong language and not related to the question specs